# What is the difference between 'wavedec' and 'dwt' in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signals, wavelet

What is the difference between 'wavedec' and 'dwt' in Matlab?
Which command should be used to decompose a signal?

Comment: `dwt`=Single-level discrete 1-D wavelet transform. `wavedec`=Multilevel 1-D wavelet decomposition. I think its quite clear in the documentation!

Comment: So, the transform used to decompose signals, and then for 1-level decomposition using 'wavedec' give the same result of 'dwt'

Comment: try this code

chan1 = randn(128,1);
[cA1,cD1] = dwt(chan1,'db4');
[C,L] = wavedec(chan1,1,'db4');
C(1:L(1))
cA1

Answer (score 2):

The difference is single level and multi-level decomposition of the signal.
dwt can be used for just applying wavelet transform to a signal. But, in images where you are trying to extract information, I have seen mostly multi-level decomposition is preferred.